# Treat As Content Coding in a Link

Tags: ampscript

I am currently trying to code data from a data extension to pull into a link, see example below:

www.xyz.com/%%=v(@link)=%% where "www.xyz.com/" is the link and the content from the data extension is %%=v(@link)=%%.

When trying the preview test section of exact target, the links function fully. however, when testing the email send to my email, the links get redirected and do not function. is there any way to get around this redirect so that the links fully function when the email goes out to customers?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
%%[
var @link, @linkconcat
set @link = AttibuteValue('dataextensionlinkfield')
set @linkconcat = concat('https://www.xyz.com/', @link)
]%%

Go here to buy stuff: %%=redirectTo(@linkconcat)=%%
```

There's a couple different things going on here -- 1 is that your consolidating your links so you don't have nested variables that can break if you don't go through all your HTML and update everything.

AND the main thing is the redirectTo function is best practice (search it on this forum for more details) to allow for Link Click tracking and a common redirect issue you're experiencing.